# Need to test static Utils class

Tags: java, android, oop, inheritance

I have a few classes that share some common stateless methods so I created a Util class here is an example method:

```
public class FileUtil {
  private static final int kFILEBUFSIZE = 128;
  private static FileUtil fSingleton;

  public static synchronized FileUtil instance() {
    if( fSingleton == null )
      fSingleton = new FileUtil();
    return fSingleton;
  } 
.....
```

So all the classes that use these methods do a static import of the Util class. Now the issue comes when I am testing, static methods can't be overridden. Would it be better to create a base class which all the other classes extend (doesn't really follow the "is a" principal), or just move the static methods that need to be overridden for tests into the main classes?

During my tests I'd like to do override the instance() and just return a mocked object.

Comment: Why do you need to override these methods during tests? Unless they use some external dependency which is a pain to work with, just keep them as they are. You really don't need to isolate the code you're testing from *all* other code.

Comment: By the time you answered I was writing the exact same thing :D

Comment: As a side note you would make your Util class final and make not public constructor :)

Comment: If you need to mock it, it shouldn't be static! Otherwise, just leave it be (as others have already said).

Comment: I never deal with File directly in my code. I use an interface (eg [InputStreamSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/core/io/InputStreamSource.html) or [Resource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html)). This way I can easily mock with a StringResource or similar.

Comment: Example: iShouldReturnSomething() -> Test -> Return a mocked object instead.

Comment: Why would iNeedAReponse() be static?

Comment: @StenKin: That example isn't clear at all. It would be a lot better if you'd improve your *question* to clarify. The sample utility method you've given at the moment definitely doesn't need to be mocked.

Answer (score 4):

I hope that is not actual code, since String does not have a size() method in any java I recognize.

Test the methods in a jUnit (or other unit testing framework).

for example

```
public class TestBlammy
{
    @Test
    public void test1()
    {
       assertEquals(5, Util.sizeOf("12345"));
       assertEquals(0, Util.sizeOf(""));
       assertEquals(0, Util.sizeOf(null)); // you don't currently handle this, but should.
    }
}
```